postgreSQL server ver. 14 , how to import dump ( A directory-based archive ) file using pg_restore by remaping schema name?
postgreSQL server ver. 14 , how to import dump ( A directory-based archive ) file using pg_restore by remaping schema name?
we need to use pg_dump efficiently with parameter j , as a result we significantly reduced backup time. Then pg_dump output is a directory based achive
the problem is how to remap schema name during restoring.
Oracle solves this problem with remap_schema parameter.

Can't you just rename it after loading?

If you have a linux system you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885462/5193536

AFAIK, there are no remap_schema features to import the data into a different schema using pg_restore in PostgreSQL but there is a workaround for that by configuring the schema in the users before we import the data. You can dump the backup using pg_dump into the SQL output, and then made the changes related to the schema name in the SQL output file, later run pg_restore using the SQL output file.
